# Not able to run command in Userdata with cloud-formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, devops, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

```
"AppLaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
                "EbsOptimized": false,
                "ImageId": {
                    "Ref": "amiID"
                },
                "InstanceType": "t3.small",
                "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                    "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                   "har-extractor /home/ubuntu/work/git.codavel.com.har --output /home/ubuntu/extract/\n"
                     ]]
                   }
                },
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "InstanceSecGroup"
                    }
                ],
            }
            },
```

Hi Team,
This is my cloud-formation template for auto-scaling and it is working properly but the thing is I am running one command in **Userdata** that is not working. I have tried every possible thing but didn't work at all. And If I am running this manually this command is working.
So please help me out in this how will I resolve this issue. I am running this command on Ubuntu machine.

Comment: What does not work the CloudFormation or it doesn't run?

Answer (score 2):

You can debug this by taking a look at the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file which contains the [output for your Linux Userdata commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts).

If this does not provide any useful debug, the next necessary step would be try running the command as `root` which mimics exactly what the functionality carries out.

Comment: For this I need to SSH into the Server which is created by this template Right?

Comment: Yes you would need to do this

Comment: Chris
Its showing that the file is not present
Actually I have mounted a S3 bucket and then create a AMI of that machine and when I SSH into new machine which is created by template that mounted bucket is ot present on new machine how is it possible?

Comment: The log file? Are you checking as `root`?

Comment: Chris My question is why that AMI is removed S3 bucket which is mounted permanently.

Comment: Ah, you should not mount an S3 bucket its generally not designed for that. However, for the sake of the implementation if you're using NFS to mount it, it would need an entry in the `fstab` file. Are you using third party software to mount it?

Comment: Yes I am using S3FS, so how will i do this becouse my data is present in S3 bucket and I Want to server that data this is an important part.
or need to run mounting command in userdata as well?

Comment: Amazon S3 is an object storage system, not a file system. It is not recommended to use tools such as `s3fs` to mount S3 on a computer, especially for Production usage. If you wish to share a filesystem between multiple Amazon EC2 instances, you can use Amazon Elastic File System (Amazon EFS).

Comment: I agree with what @JohnRotenstein has said here, I would suggest for testing your solution yes temporarily add it to userdata but look at moving to EFS. :)

Comment: Yes I have solved that Issue for passing value in User data

Comment: OK great, glad this is solved take a look for the future at using EFS over S3 for sharing file storage between hosts :)

Comment: I have a question that Can i pass parameter in Userdata like 
har-extractor /home/ubuntu/work/git.codavel.com.har --output /home/ubuntu/extract
for the place of this i want to run 
har-extractor /home/ubuntu/work/$(filename) --output /home/ubuntu/extract

and this file name i want to run thrugh parameter is there any solution
Appreciate for your help

Comment: Hi @shubhamkamboj you cannot directly pass a parameter into your userdata, if you're trying to retrieve a variable that you might modify over time you could use systems manager parameter store. Then retrieve it by doing `$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "MyStringParameter" --query "Parameter.Value" --output text)` or something similar